# Mongoose aggregate: return not _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

these are my documents:

```
{shopId: "aaa", customerId: "bbb", customerName: "xxx", value: 12}  
{shopId: "aaa", customerId: "ccc", customerName: "yyy", value: 12}  
{shopId: "aaa", customerId: "bbb", customerName: "xxx", value: 12}  
{shopId: "ddd", customerId: "bbb", customerName: "xxx", value: 12}
```

I want to find out how much money was spent in selected shop by given customer.

I know how to do it:

```
Docs.aggregate(
    [{ $match: { shopId: selectedShop } },
        {
            $group: {
                    _id: "$customerId",
                    totalVisits: { $sum: 1 },
                    totalValue: { $sum: "$value" }
                }
            }
        ], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                //

            } else {
                //

            }
        }
    );
```

Problem is that the result I get contains `_id: "$customerId"` field and I want to get `customerName` and hide `customerId`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator to hide fields later in the stage.

In short: Add something like the following to your pipeline to hide your customer ID.

```
{ $project : { _id : 0, totalVisits : 1 , totalValue : 1 } }
```

To include the customer name you could use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#definition) in your group operator.

If you want the customer name and hide the customer ID then why not just group on customer name?

Comment: Customer name is not unique so I guess I cannot group on that.

Comment: Ah ok - I just assumed that due to the dummy data in your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. To get the "customerName" you need to use the  [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator operator in your [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

```
Docs.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { shopId: selectedShop } },
        { $group: {
            "_id": "$customerId",
            "totalVisits": { $sum: 1 },
            "totalValue": { $sum: "$value" },
            "customerName": { $first: "$customerName" }
        }}
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            //
         } else {
            //
         }
      }
);
```

Of course you can always add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage if you don't want the `_id` field but it will cause a drop of performance.